# Trouble with GCM client android, no message received on device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use Cloud Messaging with my application to send push messages. I believe that my setup is correct because in the logcat I can see that the GCM message is received and my service is called (not sure about this).

Following is the logcat output:

```
10-11 19:08:53.650   2214-18323/com.google.process.gapps I/GCM﹕ GCM message com.utilapps.newapp 0:1444570718421579%36e01bcef9fd7ecd
10-11 19:08:53.692  15744-16846/com.utilapps.newapp W/GcmListenerService﹕ Received message with unknown type: 1
```

Comment: It would be useful if you provide the code of your GcmListenerService, and your AndroidManifest.xml